# Is there a function like ''AsDateTime'' that converts retrieved data from SQL Server to time?

Tags: c++, sql-server, datetime, c++builder, vcl

In a particular table, I have a type `time(0)` for a particular column in Microsoft SQL Server.

I am trying to retrieve a data from that column and convert it to a c++ type that would only have time parameters.

As for now, my chosen Type on C++ is `TDateTime` which has `AsDateTime` to convert retrieved data to this particular type, but as I'm compiling, `Field 'x' not found` appears as the error that concerns me.

I have found that `TDateTime` as a special type `TTime` that would fit my requirements but it doesn't seem to have a converter.

Is there any type that I could use or a function that I don't know that would do what I'm looking for?

The code looks like this.

```
Class
```

```
class Test
{
   public:
      TDateTime date;
}
```

```
Query line
```

```
date = Qry->FieldByName("x")->AsDateTime;
```

[image: SQLServer Design]

Comment: Swapped the rad-studio tag with vcl because this isn't an issue with RAD Studio and is a question about finding an appropriate function that will be in VCL if it exists.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the problem isn't the conversion from `TDateTime` to `TTime` but that the field `x` isn't found in whatever dataset is used there.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I've tried switching the type of the field x to a datetime instead of time and there was no error that occured. Since I don't want to input unnecessary data such as the date into this particular type, I am using the time type.

Comment: @ChristopherNguyenHoang Show a [mcve] reproducing the problem as required here please.

Comment: Use `"MondayStartTime"` instead of `"x"` when calling `FieldByName()`.